# Unable to connect to my openfire server:python

Tags: python, openfire

I have installed openfire server on my fedora 20 machine, and i am trying to connect and insert a new user with following..

```
from openfire import UserService
api = UserService("192.xxx.x.xxx:9090/", "SecretKey")
```

i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_openfire-0.2.3_beta-py2.7.egg/openfire/user_service.py", line 60, in add_user
'groups': groups_str,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_openfire-0.2.3_beta-py2.7.egg/openfire/base.py", line 34, in _submit_request
raise HTTPException(e.reason)
openfire.exception.HTTPException: unknown url type: 192.xxx.x.xxx
```

i have taken reference from this url:

https://github.com/plazix/python-openfire/blob/master/docs/user_service.md

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prepending your URL with the protocol. Eg. HTTP:

```
api = UserService("http://192.xxx.x.xxx:9090/", "SecretKey")
```

Obviously, you also need to use a valid IP address or host name instead of "192.xxx.x.xxx".

Comment: Yes it is connected, but getting the following error `openfire.exception.HTTPException: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
`